# Reporting Services Error: rsServerConfigurationError

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services, windows-server

The company I work for has locally a MS Server 2005, with SQL server 2005. The problem that they are facing is that although they can log in to their platform and do most of the things they want (like importing data into the database, editing etc.) they get the message below when they are trying to get a report:

> Reporting Services Error: The Report Server has encountered a configuration error; more details in the log files (rsServerConfigurationError)

In the log file I can't find any error or any change. What should I do?

Comment: You're not providing enough details for us to help you, nor are you telling us what you've done so far to investigate/resolve the problem. (Note that you can edit your question to add more details.)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281347.aspx